# Виртуальные поддомены на разных серверах

Tags: apache2, vps, поддомены, users

Имеется несколько виртуальных серверов. На основном есть привязанный домен с виртуальными поддоменами с помощью apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias u*.site.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html/users/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

При создании папки, например, "u15", создается поддомен, вида "u15.site.com". Когда место на диске закончится, нужно, чтобы на втором сервере было продолжение. Изначальное число поддоменов неизвестно. Подскажите, как реализовать такую задачу?

Comment: Самое сложное как я понимаю в настройках DNS для части поддоменов указать адрес первого сервера, а для второй части второго сервера. Ну либо не через DNS а через проксирующий nginx на одном из серверов сделать то же самое. могу предложить заранее начать разносить поддомены на разные сервера по определеному правилу, например четные на один, нечетные на другой и сделать генератор конфигов dns/nginx/apache

Comment: Делают же как то на бесплатных хостингах ? Вряд ли они заранее создают поддомены.. Повторюсь, что изначально число поддоменов неизвестно, они создаются динамически.

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы в динамическом создании DNS-записей. Сложнее динамически создавать новые сервера :)

Comment: можно поподробнее, по моему это не совсем то

Comment: может ProxyPass подойдет?